# Cannot pass variables to a dynamic pivot query from Razor Web Pages

Tags: c#, sql-server, razor

My Dynamic Pivot Query is as follows

```
    var sql_ovrd = @"DECLARE @out VARCHAR(MAX)
                SELECT @out = COALESCE(@out+'],[' ,'') + Hospital_Name
                FROM Hospitals
                SELECT @out = '['+@out+ ']'

                DECLARE @sql varchar(1000)
                SET @sql = '
                SELECT * FROM        
                (
                    SELECT  OVRCATEGORY.OVRCATEGORY AS OVRCAT, OVRCATEGORY.OVRCATEGORY AS OVRCATEGORY, Hospitals.Hospital_Name AS Hospital, OVRREPORTED.OVRCatID,
                            MONTH(OVRREPORTED.DATERECEIVED) AS [Month], YEAR(OVRREPORTED.DATERECEIVED) AS [YEAR]
                    FROM    OVRREPORTED 
                            INNER JOIN OVRCategory ON OVRReported.OVRCatID = OVRCategory.OVRCatID
                            INNER JOIN Hospitals ON OVRReported.Hospital_ID = Hospitals.Hospital_ID
                    WHERE   ovrreported.cancel_id=0 AND MONTH(OVRREPORTED.DATERECEIVED) =@0 AND YEAR(OVRREPORTED.DATERECEIVED)=@1
                ) AS T 

                PIVOT (COUNT(OVRCAT) FOR Hospital IN ('+@out+')) AS P'
                EXEC (@sql)"; //
var ovrd_data = db.Query(sql_ovrd,3,2015);
```

This keeps giving me error message that "Must declare the scalar variable "@0". Am I doing something silly?

The web grid I am trying to create works fine when I remove "AND MONTH(OVRREPORTED.DATERECEIVED) =@0 AND YEAR(OVRREPORTED.DATERECEIVED)=@1" from the Where Clause. Also when I try to execute directly on the sql studio as "AND MONTH(OVRREPORTED.DATERECEIVED) =3 AND YEAR(OVRREPORTED.DATERECEIVED)=2015" it is working perfectly.

Is it not possible to pass variables from Web Pages Razor syntax to a dynamic query?

Comment: The error message looks accurate. You are using variables `@0` and `@1` without declaring them first. sql-server doesn't know these variables, and they have no value.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. But usually in web pages razor. I just pass variables into query like this only. and it works fine. I will try the sp_executesql way. I am sure though how it is done. This is my first attempt at a dynamic sql pivot.

Answer (score 0):

To pass values into variable in dynamic SQL you need to use **sp_executesql** sys stored procedure see MSDN explication : [enter link description here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you kindly link me to an example which shows how to pass this from web pages framework? For example: The last two lines of my code should be EXEC sp_executesql (@sql)"; //
var ovrd_data = db.Query(sql_ovrd,3,2015);